# How do I log every data change that has been made in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, logging

I have a profile page (less than 10k users) and I need to track every change and update that is made through out the application, by the users. Whether a user updates the profile picture or adds an extra space in a "comments" field, I need to store the previous data.
In short: **I need to store everything**.

Is there some sort of "tracking-history-and-changes-in-sql-server" software or do I have to implement it myself?

If I have to implement it myself I can think of three ways to do it:

1. I keep everything in the same table
   but I add a *key* column that
   specifies which row is active
   and which is old.
2. I add a new table called *history*
   where I store the column name that had the
   change, when it was changed and what
   the old data was.
3. I add a history table for each table
   in the database. It looks the same
   but only keep track of each tables
   history.

Has anyone had a similar problem and how did you solve it?

> This was built using mvc 4 and it's a
>   normal website.

**EDIT**
I'm mostly interested in existing solutions/software, but If there are none I would have to do it myself.
Has anyone used [SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/)?

Comment: and what is the client software? is it some desktop application or web?

Comment: In response to your edit : Not that specific package but something with the same functionality. Its very usefull but not for what you want to do. You need to know who made the change not just what changed.

Comment: Yeah, that's an good point, I need that too. Couldn't that be added manually with this software though?

Comment: You do something like have a "last updated by" column and update that. It would show you who did the last change when you did a compare. It would be messy though and only show you the last update. I would strongly recommend keeping your history in the db. Go for either my answer or Microprocessor's both are valid approaches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where I worked last everything had to be logged fully. (working with goverment organisations). We never updated or deleted data.

What you would do is have a start date and an end date on each row. To do an update you would update the old data to have an enddate then insert a new row in the table. To do a delete you would put an enddate on the row with a null enddate. We also had an "updated by" column to put the userid

Comment: How did you handle unique keys if you kept everything in the same table... or didn't you have any?

Comment: You would have the unique key as a combination with the enddate. Ie email and enddate. You can have multiple ended but only one current

Comment: Sounds like a real nightmare trying to figure out what was previously in the database especially when joins are involved.

Comment: @Adrian - So you would go with #3?

Comment: @Adrian its not too bad. You don't often need to look at historical data, you just want the current one (so just have where enddate is null)

Comment: @Niklas: It depends on how often I will actually have to use the logged data. #3 looks less messy, but also a like lot more effort. Also, Tom's approach does not work with update queries, but he pointed that out already.

Answer (score 1):

I used the third approach to do that but didn't create a history table for all tables of my DB but history tables for most important tables. You can use `triggers` to do that , create `trigger` for `Update`. You can read more about Triggers [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) and [here](http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=15510)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft offers [Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) and [Change Data Capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) for awhile now. These technically offer the tracking of *all* your changes in your database, which suits your purpose. Just note that CT is available in most versions, whereas CDC used to be only available in Enterprise until SQL Server 2016, where they made it available for Standard too.

ApexSQL Log does pretty much the same as well, but if you're using SQL Server then it's integrated in your software already.

Answer (score 0):

have you considered enabling full transaction logging on your database and then using some of the log reading tools to monitor data changes. [ApexSQL Log](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx) is by far the best log reader on the market but there are other solutions out there. SQL Log Rescue from Red Gate is free but it's only for sql server 2000.

Using this approach you dont need to make any other changes in your database or in your application since every transaction is automatically logged when database is in full recovery mode.

Hope this helps.